# Play console warning with native code, React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, compiler-warnings, google-play-console, ndk-build

I had a warning form Google Play Console, that my aab contains native code and I need to upload symbol files. I have done all the steps from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en, and if i enter the ndkPath = 'C:/Users/{PCName}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle' in build.gradle, its work fine, but there are https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-agp-ndk , I understand, that aab can create symbol files automatically and upload them without ndkPath. I have set Enviroment variables with path to ndk, but without ndkPath in build.gradle it doesn't work.
gradle version - 7.0.2,
compileSdkVersion = 30,
ndkVersion = 23.1.7779620

can someone help me?